# Ant 'get' task recursion

Tags: ant, get, wget

How can I recursively download files via the 'get' task?

I'm looking for the Ant equivalent of:

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=5 --level=0 ftp://ftp.some.host/dir1/dir2...../dir6
```

I have this snippet in build.xml:

```
<get src="${ftpPath}" dest="tempfolder" verbose="true" />
```

Results in:

```
      [get] Getting: <FTP_URL_HERE>
      [get] To: <dir>/tempfolder
      [get] ....
  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
  Total time: 0 seconds
```

Nothing gets downloaded. I'm assuming the 'get' task is only for files. Unfortunately, it's not an option to list every single file (this can go in the 1000s) within the <url> tags.

I'm a little hesitant running the wget command via the 'exec' task, since Windows doesn't natively have wget, and I want to maintain platform-independence with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can nest a fileset or otherwise specify an include pattern for the `@src` or a [`<url>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#url) resource.

However, if your `${ftpPath}` is an FTP path, then **you could use the [`<ftp>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html), which does support filesets and patterns**:

```
  <ftp action="get"
       server="ftp.some.host"
       userid="anonymous"
       password="me@myorg.com">
    <fileset>
      <include name="**/dir*/**"/>
    </fileset>
  </ftp>
```

Comment: I didn't go with this approach (jar dependency). I decided to run 'wget' via exec (bash). I'll deal with Windows later.